# Route QEMU VM traffic through hosts VPN

Tags: openvpn, bridge, route, qemu, iproute2

tl;dr Host connects via VPN to the internet and a VM on this host doesn't go through this VPN (but it should). I think the network config isn't quite correct.

### The host

The host (arch Linux) connects to a VPN network using openvpn and a config file, so there's a TUN device (`tun0`) created by openvpn. The physical device is called `eno1`.

I searched a lot in the internet and wrote a script to create a bridged network where the VM can connect to. This script creates a bridge `br0` and a TAP device `tap0`. It also edits the routing table, so that I have normal internet access on the host through my VPN. The table looks like this:

```
~# netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.1.102.1      128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun0
10.1.102.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 tun0
81.95.5.34      192.168.178.1   255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 br0
128.0.0.0       10.1.102.1      128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun0
192.168.178.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 br0
```

The addresses and configuration look like this:

```
~# ip addr
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e0:3f:49:48:eb:6e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.178.29/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
95: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.1.102.248/24 brd 10.1.102.255 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fdbf:1d37:bbe0:0:22:6:0:1248/112 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5ee5:c367:ab47:5928/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
96: tap0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7a:22:5d:99:01:06 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
97: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7a:22:5d:99:01:06 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.178.120/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global noprefixroute br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::d731:e2c8:a4f8:224e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7822:5dff:fe99:106/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
98: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:10:76:e0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::790c:464b:74f6:6754/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe10:76e0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

### The VM

As mentioned above, it's a centos 7 VM I run using the virt-manager and `/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64` as emulator. In the network settings I use a shared device (`br0`) with `virtio` as device model.

On the VMs side it looks much simpler. The routing table:

```
~# netstat -rn
Kernel IP Routentabelle
Ziel            Router          Genmask         Flags   MSS Fenster irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.178.1   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.178.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

And the addresses:

```
~# ip addr
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:10:76:e0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.178.105/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global noprefixroute dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 860890sec preferred_lft 860890sec
    inet6 fe80::47ed:5e58:2c27:6b50/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

### My Problem:

The VM doesn't seem so send the traffic through my VPN (VM has faster ping times to google then the host and `mtr` is different too). Instead directly to the internet. I think I have to edit the routing tables, but I don't know how.

I tired to change the IP of the default route to `192.168.178.120` (`br0` IP) and also to `192.168.178.29` (`eno1` IP) but that didn't work. I also created an IP for the `tap0` and set it as default route in the VM, but that didn't work either.

Comment: There's already an anomaly since eno1 part of the br0 bridge and br0 both have an IP. Only br0 should have an IP  (or neither of them, but that's a different config requiring an additional pair of veth) preferably from a config with eno1 enslaved first to inherit its MAC address, which wasn't the case here . Is it mandatory for the VM to be in the "physical" LAN instead of a routed/nated LAN? The later case should be easier to handle. So why is the setup as it is?

Comment: So br0 should have the MAC address of eno1 and eno1 shouldn't have an IP address (but br0 should)? I'll try to achieve that.

The VM needs internet access and a connection to the host (for an NFS-share). I actually don't know if being part of the physical device is needed for that.

There's no specific reason why it is as it is. I just tried many things, because none of the tutorials (on the Arch-Wiki, on StackOverflow, on many forums) worked.